# Adding OfType<T> on MongoCollection "breaks" the behaviour of UpdateOneAsync

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I've run into what I can only understand to be a bug in the C# driver.

This [gist](https://gist.github.com/rshillington/1c63d0a17cf7a1aa24e6#file-program-cs) illustrates the problem.

If I run

```
collection.UpdateOneAsync(
    "{ \"_id\" : ObjectId(\"5656277cd4d37b13b4e7e009\"), \"Addresses.Index\" : 4 },
    "{ \"$set\" : { \"Addresses.$\" : { \"_t\" : [\"Address\", \"EmailAddress\"], \"Index\" : 4, \"MailTo\" : \"Never@home.com\" } } }")
```

I get the desired result.

If however I use the Builders to build the filter definition and update definition like so:

`var filter = Builders<Person>
        .Filter
        .And(Builders<Person>.Filter.Eq(p => p.Id, person.Id),
                Builders<Person>.Filter.Eq("Addresses.Index", 4));`

`var update = Builders<Person>.Update.Set("Addresses.$", new EmailAddress { Index = 4, MailTo = "Never@home.com" });`

then I must change my call to update to be

`await collection.OfType<Person>().UpdateOneAsync(filter, update);`

and the call to OfType results in the wrong address being replaced.

Comment: is collection a `IQueryable<Base>` or a `IEnumerable<Base>`? I bet you it is a IQueryable.

Comment: collection is an IMongoCollection<Base>

Comment: Oh, ok. So it is using [`IMongoCollection.OfType<T>`](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/current/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_IMongoCollection_1_OfType__1.htm) not the [`Enumerable.OfType<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913(v=vs.100).aspx) or [`Queryable.OfType<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344857(v=vs.100).aspx) extension methods. No idea then.

Comment: This is unrelated to the driver. The generated filter is correct. But it seems you may have found a bug in MongoDB itself.

Comment: OfType is merely amending the filter to include the discriminator. My suggestion here would be to repro this in the shell. What version of the server are you using?

Comment: @CraigWilson this repros for me on 2.6.7 (also checked with the profiling collection).

Comment: @RalphShillington I suggest reporting this and posting a link here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is unrelated to the MongoDB C# driver, but it seems to be a bug in MongoDB itself when the type is used in the query.

You can see that this causes the same issue without using `OfType`, but specifying the type field explicitly (i.e. `"_t"`):

```
var filter = Builders<Person>.Filter.And(
    new BsonDocument("_t", "Person"),
    Builders<Person>.Filter.Eq(p => p.Id, person.Id), 
    Builders<Person>.Filter.Eq("Addresses.Index", 4));
var update = Builders<Person>.Update.Set(
    "Addresses.$", 
    new EmailAddress { Index = 4, MailTo = "Never@home.com" });
await db.GetCollection<Person>("Objects").UpdateOneAsync(filter, update);
```

You can see the query this will generate with this piece of code:

```
Console.WriteLine(db.GetCollection<Person>("Objects").Find(filter));
```

And the query is the following which is perfectly correct:

```
{ "_t" : "Person", "_id" : ObjectId("5656356f64c22e5d38aeb92e"), "Addresses.4 }
```

Comment: The problem might be that the discriminator is persisted as an array and is matching the 2nd element of the _t array... And the positional operator ($) in the update is using that position in the update statement.

Comment: @CraigWilson seems very likely. It indeed doesn't repro when `_t` is just a simple field.